# How Can I Change this Wordpress Image URL

Tags: wordpress, image, url

http://zimbuktu.net

I go to Appearance > Editor in Wordpress but I can't see any instance of "http://www.zimbuktu.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/homeBnr.jpg" in style.css.

Does anyone know where I could try looking?

Answer (score 0):

Do check in Wordpress admin > appearance > theme setting or appearance > customize. If you didn't found the image in these options then it will be in theme just go to index.php or home.php according to your theme files. It will be in it, and it could be a custom made page too selected as front page have a look at it too.